# Creating a custom view: how can I extend a class and access the base class's private member variables?

Tags: java, android, oop, custom-view, android-custom-view

As an exercise, I am trying to extend `ImageButton` to add some features I think would be useful. One, in particular, is a drow shadow. I've hit the proverbial wall with this one.

It seems to me, that a class extending `BitmapDrawable` is necessary. This class contains a `Paint` object used to draw the bitmap to the screen. If I had access to this `Paint` object... all I would have to do is call it's `setShadowLayer()` method... but, alas, it is `private`. There is a `public` method, `getPaint()` that will return the paint object, but any modifications to it would be useless unless there were a corresponding `setPaint()` method. (There isn't.)

Currently, my thought process looks something like the following...

1. Create class `ShadowBitmapDrawable` which `extends BitmapDrawable`
2. Within this class, somehow alter the `BitmapDrawable`'s `Paint` object with `Paint`'s `setShadowLayer()` method.
3. In my custom `ImageButton` class, call `setImageDrawable(Drawable d)`, and pass it my `ShadowBitmapDrawable` object.

Step 2 is the road block. What can I do to change `BitmapDrawable`'s `Paint` object? Note that I added my thought process only as an indicator of where I am in this problem. I am open to other suggestions.

Here are some references:

- [BitmapDrawable source](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=graphics/java/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.java;h=501374b02a58e920654c345aeb62fa10da06b612;hb=HEAD) (extends `Drawable` to draw bitmaps)
- [ImageView source](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/java/android/widget/ImageView.java;h=46f7db484b45a87a57de729283e0fabbccb1e645;hb=HEAD) (base class of `ImageButton`)
- [Drawable source](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=graphics/java/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.java;h=965512563e33a5fa443b28e7110777f6e5bae0bf;hb=HEAD)

P.S. I have a bad feeling I already know the answer I'm going to get, and I'm not going to like it. Thought I'd post the question anyways and hope for the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What can I do to change BitmapDrawable's Paint object?

Clone `BitmapDrawable` into your project, refactor it into your own package, make the data member `protected` (or provide a `protected` setter or something), use your modified `BitmapDrawable`, and test the heck out of it.

Comment: Sounds interesting. Do I clone the Android repository, add it as a library project in eclipse, add the library to my build path, and make my modifications? If not, could you point me to a online resource to get me started in the right direction?

Comment: "Do I clone the Android repository, add it as a library project in eclipse, add the library to my build path, and make my modifications?" -- no. "If not, could you point me to a online resource to get me started in the right direction?" -- click the link to the source code for `BitmapDrawable` in your post. Highlight the source code with your mouse. Press <Ctrl>-<C> to copy it. Create a new Java source file in your project. Paste in the code you copied. Change the package name to something other than `android.widget`.

Comment: Only problem is that the `inflate()` method uses `Styleable`'s from `com.android.internal.R`. From my understanding, we cannot include anything from this internal branch of the package tree. Any suggestions?

Comment: Comment out the `inflate()` method. You won't be using that. When you inflate an XML resource that refers to a bitmap, it would use `inflate()`, but in that case it won't be using your `BitmapDrawable` clone, let alone your custom subclass.